# Macro enabled workbook not running

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to ensure that for each row in my spreadsheet, if cell B or C is not populated (in the range), then a message box alerts the user - and doesn't allow it to be saved.

I have the workbook saved as a Macro enabled (XLSM) file - but the Workbook_BeforeSave doesn't appear to be triggering.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
MsgBox "hi"
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 4)).Select
Stop
 
'turn off events to avoid code retriggering itself
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rng2 In rng1
    If Cells(rng2.Row, "B") = vbNullString Then
       MsgBox "Please Enter Something in Cell B - your entry will be deleted", vbOKOnly
       rng2.Value = vbNullString
    End If
    If Cells(rng2.Row, "C") = vbNullString Then
       MsgBox "Please Enter Something in Cell C - your entry will be deleted", vbOKOnly
       rng2.Value = vbNullString
    End If
    
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of macro in workbook]

Can anyone see where I may have gone wrong? Macros are enabled for the workbook.

Thanks for any advice,

Mark

Comment: This is because you have `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Comment: Is it in the correct workbook? Select Workbook then BeforeSave from the two drop-downs at the top of your screenshot. If this doesn't select your code, but creates an empty procedure stub, then move your code into this stub.

Comment: Hi Andy - yes, it's in WorkBook_BeforeSave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow in your code, you have disabled the events, thus the `Save` event is not caught. Try the following:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, while you are selecting the Visual Basic Editor;
- Write `Application.EnableEvents = True` on the [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/use-the-immediate-window) that shows up;
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;

Now the events would be activated.

---

As mentioned by Jeep, using error handling is a good idea in this case, thus the events are always enabled back if something "bad" happens during code execution:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error GoTo Workbook_BeforeSave_Error

    'code here        

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Workbook_BeforeSave_Error:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in Workbook_BeforeSave"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - thank you - I tried that, but get the message: This formula is missing a range reference or a defined name.

Comment: @MarkTait - so congrats, the events are working, you have made it to the code! :)

Comment: Sorry - when I press Ctl + G - and paste in Applications.EnableEvents = True - that's when I get the error - it's not accepting that into the immediate window.  Thanks

Comment: @MarkTait - Remove the `s` from `Applications` and try again :)

Comment: Sorry - was a typo - it is Application.EnableEvents - the window that pops up when I press Ctl + G is: GoTo - the only place I can type is in the Reference box.

Comment: @MarkTait  - I see. Select your code and then press Ctrl+G. It opens the immediate window. Write there. :)

Comment: @MarkTait - see here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/use-the-immediate-window

Comment: ... and use error control so that you don't get caught without events in the future.